# How to select different dates from one column in DATEDIFF sql

Tags: mysql, sql, data-warehouse, datediff, star-schema

I'm working on a data warehouse where I have one fact table 'Inventory' and three dimension tables: Product, Location and Time. Each dimension table is linked to the fact table with foreign key on their id.

In my fact table, I have two different dates, each references the primary key idTime in my Time table dimension.

My problem is the following: I want to find the average difference of days between two dates using DATEDIFF statement. Here is my query:

```
select P.nameProduct, AVG (DATEDIFF(
        (select T.fulldate from Time as T, Inventory as I 
                        WHERE I.idTime_stockout = T.idTime),
        (select T.fulldate from Time as T, Inventory as I 
                        WHERE I.idTime_resupply = T.idTime)
    )) as Time_to_stock_out
FROM Inventory as I, Product as P, Time as T
WHERE I.idProduct = P.idProduct
GROUP BY P.nameProduct;
```

'fulldate' represent the date column in my Time dimension table.
'idTime_stockout' and 'idTime_stockout' represent two date column in my Fact table which references my Time table

In the average datediff i only want the dates that meet my criteria and not all the dates of the column. So for the first argument I select all the dates of the 'idTime_stockout' column and for the second argument all the dates of the 'idTime_resupply' column. And after I apply my conditions with a WHERE statement.

But I have a problem because the query returns the following error message:

```
ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Can you help me to resolve this problem please ?

Quentin

Answer (score 1):

maybe,you should using 'limit 1' after the both subquery in the DateDiff field?

```sql
select P.nameProduct,
AVG(DATEDIFF((select T.fulldate from Time as T,
Inventory as I WHERE I.idTime_stockout = T.idTime limit 1),
(select T.fulldate from Time as T, 
Inventory as I WHERE I.idTime_resupply = T.idTime limit 1)))
 as Time_to_stock_out
FROM Inventory as I, Product as P WHERE I.idProduct = P.idProduct GROUP BY P.nameProduct;
```

Comment: I am unsure if this is an attempt to reply (comment) or an attempt to answer the question. I would swing with the former due to your question mark - if this is the case, please wait until you have sufficient reputation to post comments. If this is an attempt to answer, please flesh your answer with further and fuller details as to why this could be the answer along with some code example

Comment: hmm you mean as an argument of DateDiff statement ? I think there are only two required arguments in this statement ?

Comment: datediff function need both parameter are single date-formatted string.The sql code you show above return a collections.